# Facebook Pixel Error: Parameter "currency" is invalid for event "Purchase"

Tags: facebook

```
fbq("track","Purchase",{value:140.96,currency:'TL'});
```

**Facebook is giving pixel error. But I do not see any problems. Do you see any problems?**

Comment: You need to use a currency code that is defined by [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) - `TL` isn’t one of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
fbq("track","Purchase",{value:140.96,currency:'TRY'});
```

All supported currency should be 3 chars. I hope when you specify TL, you mean Turkish Lira (i.e. TRY)